# Python: requests - scraper does not work anymore - issue with cookie (data privacy consent)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, cookies, web-crawler

StackOverflow community,

two months ago, I created a scraper in python3 in order to scrape car ads from https://www.autoscout24.com.
The scraper uses the following [search URL](https://www.autoscout24.com/lst/porsche/911-series-(all)?sort=age&desc=1&ustate=N%2CU&size=20&page=1&pricefrom=0&priceto=100000&fregfrom=1990&fregto=1995&cy=D&atype=C&) to fetch a list of all available car ads and later on iterates through the detail pages.

Since June 26th, the scraper is not able to fetch car ads from the website anymore which - at least that's what I think- happens due to a new cookie privacy consent.
When iterating through all `<a>` tags in order to fetch the detail pages of the car ads (beginning with /offers/), no results are shown. In the past, links to the car ad detail pages were printed.

**Please find below my code for getting the car ad detail pages.**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import re

url = 'https://www.autoscout24.com/lst/porsche/911-series-(all)?sort=age&desc=1&ustate=N%2CU&size=20&page=1&pricefrom=0&priceto=100000&fregfrom=1990&fregto=1995&cy=D&atype=C&'
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)
only_a_tags = SoupStrainer("a")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml', parse_only=only_a_tags)
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    if r"/offers/" in str(link.get("href")):
        print (link.get("href"))
```

I already tried setting "cookies = {'cookieConsent': '1'}" and add it to the get request, but it still does not work.

As four eyes see more than two, I would really appreciate it if some of you might take some time to help me solve this issue.

Many thanks for your support and have a great day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import re

url = 'https://www.autoscout24.com/lst/porsche/911-series-(all)?sort=age&desc=1&ustate=N%2CU&size=20&page=1&pricefrom=0&priceto=100000&fregfrom=1990&fregto=1995&cy=D&atype=C&'

with HTMLSession() as session:
    r = session.get(url)
    r.html.render()

only_a_tags = SoupStrainer("a")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.html.html,'lxml', parse_only=only_a_tags)
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    if r"/offers/" in str(link.get("href")):
        print (link.get("href"))
```

What this is doing is rendering the JS on the page, which is what seems to be the issue, as you're scraping without rendering the JS and all the offers are pulled in by JS.

Hope this helps :)

edit: sometimes you may have to run it more than once, I'm not sure why but it seems to work on my machine most of the time

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for your quick reply.
After doing a bit of debugging due to a chromium issue (e.g. import pyppdf.patch_pyppeteer), I finally got it to work with your fix. Works great!

Thank you very much :-)